# Как использовать GetElementByID в React?

Tags: reactjs

Как использовать **GetElementByID** в React? Есть ли еще способы взаимодейстовать с DOM элементами?
Вообще, можно ли использовать **GetElementByID** и правильно ли это с точки зрения React?

Comment: а рефы вам не подходят? https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: "правильно ли это с точки зрения React" - если можно избежать этого не "уродуя" код и логику, то лучше так не делать